# Wubi install no longer boots

Tags: 12.10, boot, grub2, wubi

I dual-boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 with Wubi. I use two partition on the same HDD. My ubuntu partition was starting to run low on memory, so i added 10 GB to it. Now it won't boot into Ubuntu, it says: `Error no such device : 7802EDF027EA234`.

I restarted my computer and selected "Advanced boot options", and then Recovery mode. A bunch of text came on my screen, and the message:

```
Alert! /dev/disk/by-uuid/7802EDF027EA234 does not exist Dropping to a shell! (ash)
```

So, Boot-repair gave me the link [paste.ubuntu.com/5632890](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5632890/)

Any and all help appreciated, Thanks guys! 
-Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you modified the `NTFS` partitions because your `Ubuntu` install was running out of space, then note that this would have had no beneficial effect. Since Wubi uses a fixed virtual disk. Instead refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeWubiDisk or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk

It seems that in modifying your `NTFS` partitions, it generated new `UUIDS`. As you have an entry in your `/etc/fstab` that tries to mount `/host` on the partition with UUID `7802EDF027EA234`. And your `grub.cfg` refers to that same partition.

So that's causing the error because there is no such partition. It would be the same error if you had copied the Wubi install from another computer.

But try this. When you see the grub menu (if it doesn't show, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to make it appear), then press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit the entry and change it to look like this:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-25-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-25-generic-advanced-d9f4b9a9-784c-4bf7-b1ac-e7f43a731ef7' {
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
    set root=(loop0)
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-25-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic root=/dev/sda1 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic
```

So, in summary, you deleted a bunch of lines and changed the line starting `linux...` to refer to the `root=/dev/sda1`. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot.

After booting, drop to a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>and run `sudo update-grub`.

Also, for a Wubi install it's completely unnecessary to mount `/host` as it's done automatically for you at boot time. So delete that line from the `/etc/fstab`.