# Searched for hours need help. WUBI 12.04 won't boot after shrinking partition

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-7, wubi

Thanks in advance for the help. I've learnt a little bit reading through for the last so many hours and have finally given up and have a question...

I installed 12.04 onto my HDD D: used it for a while and everything was great. Later I shrunk my D: so that I could make the unallocated space into a new partition to use...

unfortunately my Ubuntu now won't boot due to the error message below but please read on as I have some specifics that I would like help with...

"The os couldn't be loaded because the file \Ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr is missing or contains error

I have been to this page: [Boot manager is showing \Ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr is missing or contains error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215661/boot-manager-is-showing-ubuntu-winboot-wubildr-mbr-is-missing-or-contains-error) and seen the duplicate and the link etc.

I would gladly uninstall and reinstall but I have some files on my ubuntu (on the root.disk as I've come to understand) that I need. Should have put them on my other partition in the first place I guess and I wouldn't have this problem right?

Ok so... WITHOUT BOOTING FROM A CD CAN I ACCESS THE FILES ON MY ROOT.DISK  OR BETTER YET

```
     FIX THE BOOTING ISSUE?
```

reading the below link is the boot issue is because I changed the partition where the WUBI file was installed and therefore has a new UUID? (not sure what this or a UUID yet though sorry). I see the instructions but don't understand how to see the grub menu and need some easier instructions I guess. Not even sure how to get a terminal up as I can't boot my WUBI...

[Wubi install no longer boots](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270698/wubi-install-no-longer-boots)

THanks again for the help,

Dan

Comment: Did your drive assignments change when you shrunk your drive? If the UUID changed then Ubuntu won't boot, but to get the *wubildr.mbr not found* then either the drive letter assignment changed or the file is no longer present. PS use [ext2read](http://askubuntu.com/a/272350/14916) to recover data from the `root.disk`

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the shrinkage. You threw the boot file.

This is very dangerous for Operation Systems.

**Take a look of this :** [Wubi Guide # How can I access the Wubi files from Windows](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_access_the_Wubi_files_from_Windows.3F)

If it didn't worked search again and try other keywords [google search | accessing wubi files from windows](https://www.google.gr/#q=accessing+wubi+files+from+windows)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I got rid of my windows in the end as I had some issues booting and now all is good though I lost some files... and now that I got rid of windows completely it was all so unnecessary...